# Nonnegative Integer Pairs

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

Find all pairs $(a,b)$ of non-negative integers such that $2017^a=b^6-32b+1$.

What I tried:$2016*(2017^{a-1}+2017^{a-2}+...+2017+1)=b(b-2)(b^4+b^3*2+b^2*4+b*8+16)$

I also tried to force write them

$2017^a + 255 = (b-16)^2 = 2017^a \pmod 5$

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been published for the solutions of the [48th Austrian Mathematical Olympiad National Competition](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjZxoSsg5LlAhVIdcAKHaKaDl4QFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.aau.at%2FOeMO%2Fsolutions%2FZWF%2F2017&usg=AOvVaw2G9FhZ8qC4M_aBAmTX3Uh4), Problem 4.

Answer: The two solutions are $(0,0)$ and $(0, 2)$. The problem and solution are due to Walther Janous.